# Flush NginX's SSL Buffer during Long Polling

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, go, long-polling

I'm writing an app that uses long polling to push messages to clients.  It doesn't end the request when it finishes sending a message though: it just flushes.  It works fine, even when I proxy it through nginx and access it over the internet.

```
upstream app {
  server localhost:1000;
}

server {
    listen 80;    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        send_timeout 86400;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        proxy_buffering off;
        gzip off;
    }
}
```

That is, until I enable SSL on nginx.  Then it won't flush anymore.  I can work around this by setting `ssl_buffer_size` to 1, but this negatively impacts performance.

```
upstream app {
  server localhost:1000;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key key.pem;
    ssl_buffer_size 1;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        send_timeout 86400;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        proxy_buffering off;
        gzip off;
    }
}
```

I wrote my application in Go, and I'm using the standard `Flush()` from `net/http`.  I tried using `Hijack` to get a regular TCP buffer and `Flush()` that, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You seem to have figured out that this is because if SSL buffering in nginx. What exactly are you asking to solve here?

Comment: How to do server push when ssl is enabled in nginx

Comment: if nginx doesn't have a max-latency/flush-interval option of some sort (don't think it does), then you need to set the buffer to something that that is flushed with your message size, or pad your message. If that's not acceptable, try something else, like haproxy or the Go crypto/tls package. FYI, the `http.ResponseWriter` from a TLS connection *is* an `http.Flusher`. I don't know what haproxy's behavior is offhand.

Comment: It seems the only answer here is "don't use nginx"

Comment: Would server push through nginx ssl work better if I upgraded the request to use websockets, http2, or spdy?

Comment: No idea, why not try it? f you're intent on using nginx, maybe try their mailing list, or ServerFault.

Comment: Ok, I posted it to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Go issues, but more a Nginx configuration issue. It's most probably Nginx who is holding back your data.

Your could try to [disable proxy buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering) to avoid this. Try:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key key.pem;
    ssl_buffer_size 1;

    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

P.S.: Not tested but give it a try.

Comment: That's already in my configuration above. It doesn't matter though because the ssl buffer is separate.

Comment: @NickRetallack This was not 100% clear, since you didn't pasted your whole server block for the SSL configuration.